# Cutting joist for skewed joist hanger

Tags: framing, deck, joists, beam

Do I need to cut the joist lumber's end at an angle so that it sits flushed to the beam when installing skewed joist hanger?

[image]

The below video tells me that it's not necessary.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5sQTT-xURE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no - the LSU hangers sit over the end of a square cut joist or rafter.  they wont work if you cut them on an angle.

Comment: So the picture above is correct. What nails do I use for the right side? Same 1.5" joist hanger nails?

Comment: SOP here in ontario is a 3" ardox nail.  if you can, clinch the nail over on the back side.